# Identical Test set

Tags: testing, dataset, ssas, classification, bayesian

I have some comments and i want to classify them as Positive or Negative.
So far i have an annotated dataset .

The thing is that the first 100 rows are classified as positive and the rest 100 as Negative.

I am using SQL Server Analysis-2008 R2. The Class attribute has 2 values, POS-for positive and NEG-for negative.

Also i use Naive Bayes algorithm with maximum input/output attributes=0 (want to use all the attributes) for the classification, the test set max case is set to 30%. The current score from the Lift Chart is 0.60.

Do i have to mix them up, for example 2 POS followed by 1 NEG, in order to get better classification accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

The ordering of the learning instances should not affect classification performance. The probabilities computed by Naive Bayes will be the same for any ordering of instances in the data set.

However, the selection of different test and training sets can affect classification performance. For example, some instances might be inherently more difficult to classify than others.

Are you getting similarly poor training and test performance? If your training performance is good and/or much better than your test performance, your model may be over-fitted. Otherwise, if your training performance is also poor, I would suggest (a) trying a better/stronger/more expressive classifier, e.g., SVM, decision trees etc; and/or (b) making sure your features are representive/expressive enough of the data.

Comment: I allowed the algorithm to auto select features that represent better the data and i got a score of 0.77

I thought that the more the attributes you have,the better.

Comment: More attributes is not always better. Naturally, there is trade-off where too many attributes can make the problem harder to solve (e.g. larger search space), especially if some are not very useful, but too few can under-represent the data.